# How to compose a sequence of observables in rxjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am using rxjs to handle some complex mouse gestures.

One of these gesures is to "shake" the mouse (left to right, right to left, ...) several times during a drag operation.

As I do not know whether the user will start by moving the the left or right, I am using 'race()' to accept whichever starts first.

**My problem is that when the first "shake" observer completes, the second has already completed.**

I have made a simplified example here, on jsbin (http://jsbin.com/wuzodog/3/edit?html,js,output.)

*(I am using negative numbers as "mouse left" and positive as "mouse right" in this simplified example.)*

The core of the issue is demonstrated here...

```
  const subMouseMove = new Rx.Subject<number>();

  const obLeft = subMouseMove.filter(m => m < 0);
  const obRight = subMouseMove.filter(m => m >= 0);

  const get_obLeftUntilRight = () => obLeft.takeUntil(obRight);
  const get_obRightUntilLeft = () => obRight.takeUntil(obLeft);

  const get_obShake = () => Rx.Observable.race(get_obLeftUntilRight(), get_obRightUntilLeft()); 

  const obDragShakeAndDrop = Rx.Observable.concat(
    get_obShake(),
    get_obShake(),
  );

  //sending the following values to subMouseMove 
  [-1, -2, 3, 4, -5].forEach((v, i, a) => setTimeout(() => subMouseMove.next(v), i * 10));
```

**The problem is that both instances of get_obShake() are being completed at the same time.**

The results I am getting from the jsbin are:

[image: Actual Results]

I would expect my results to be:

[image: Expected results]

When I modify the example (http://jsbin.com/wuzodog/4/edit?html,js,output), calling the "shake left/right" and the "shake right/left" directly, bypassing "race()", I get the 'expected' output.

Can anyone explain why the second shake is completing early in the first example?

Comment: I feel like this will help you understand why: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2641

Comment: I would make a small bug fix not related to the question:

`obRight` probably should take only if `m` is greater than 0, not equal, because otherwise staying in place is also an event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky, but the answer is more rational then you think. The issue is that *Race* also accepts completion as the first winning Observable.

```
const get_obLeftUntilRight = () => obLeft.takeUntil(obRight);
const get_obRightUntilLeft = () => obRight.takeUntil(obLeft);
```

When we look at these two Observables, if there is 'left' event, the first will emit and the second will complete immediately. If we get a 'right' event the first will **complete immediately** and the second...

This is probably what you want:

```
const get_obLeftUntilRight = () => obLeft.take(1).concat(obLeft.takeUntil(obRight));
const get_obRightUntilLeft = () => obRight.take(1).concat(obRight.takeUntil(obLeft));
```

Comment: Most excellent answer.

To rephrase, `get_obLeftUntilRight()` was not _requiring_ an `obLeft` before completing because of an `obRight`.  Correct?

Comment: As a follow-up question, `takeUntil(obRight)`, _consumes_ the `obRight`, so it never gets a chance to be emitted.  Is there a simple away around this issue?

Comment: Exactly. But I'm not sure I understand the follow up question

Comment: And since your two racing Observables are not intersect, you can use merge instead of race. Obervable.merge(obLeft.takeUntil(obRight), obRight.takeUntil(obLeft))

Comment: If you look at the "correct" output, you will see that "3" is never emitted.My assumption is that the `takeUntil(obRight)` is "fired" at the time when the `obRight(3)` occurs, and now the next shake (`obRight.take(1).concat(obRight.takeUntil(obLeft))`) will not see "3" but will see "4".  I am just wondering if there is a simple way to get around this so the next shake will see "3".  I hope this is moderately coherent, if not, please ignore!

Comment: As for using merge, I will actually want the user to perform several "shakes" for the gesture, so merge wont work, I think.  I tried it in the jsbin, and it was not happy.

Comment: Yes. The concat resubscribes after the first Observable completes, so it will miss an item. You can use a behaviorsubject. Enjoy: http://jsbin.com/qidomukeya/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -1):

The difference between the two jsBin outputs is that

```
** NEXT: get_obShake2 = 4
```

is missing from the first, because `race` has eliminated it.

So, it's not that the second shake is completing early, it's just a shorter sequence.

Add some `timestamp()` to check it out.

I have to say, I don't get the feeling of this code doing what you intend, but that could well be my lack of understanding.